# In which comic was it revealed that Alfred was the Joker?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, episode-identification

There was a comic book where Alfred is shown sitting alone in a room, putting on the Joker make-up, thereby revealing him as the Joker.

It was probably an alternate universe, but in which comic book did this happen?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're most likely describing this scene from [Batman: Whatever Happened to the Caped Crusader?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Whatever_Happened_to_the_Caped_Crusader%3F). Alfred isn't really The Joker, he's merely pretending to be him.

[image]

Comment: I have to note that while Alfred was telling the story, the real Joker was sitting in the same room. Just like all the others in that comic, Alfred told a false story. So he's not really the Joker.

Comment: Quite the opposite actually. Each of the guests at the funeral told their own story, and many of them were contradictory. The story was more about the way in which Batman lived rather than how he died, and as a result there were many different Batmen whose lives were represented there. What’s most telling is the fact that Bruce recognizes that the stories don’t add up, but he doesn’t know which is supposed to be the real one.

Comment: Haven't read this comic yet, but I might have to now. This excerpt reminds me of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1-v9VFqztY

Answer (score 38):

A quick search brought up [Batman #686](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Issue_686) ("Whatever Happened to the Caped Crusader? (Part 1 of 2): The Beginning of the End") from February 2009, set in an alternate version of Gotham City. It is revealed that

> Batman is dying, and is having an out of body experience in which he is present at his own wake

Alfred is recounting the tale of Batman's beginning, which was not successful. It turns out that

> Alfred hired several people to play the role of supervillains for Batman to fight. Alfred himself adopted the persona and visage of the Joker to give Batman a nemesis to focus on. (*This story was not true however, owing to the fact that the Joker himself was also present at the wake*)

Comment: Trivia: This storyline was [parodied by Dorkly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJABz1XpOI4)